# jQuery change the meaning of this in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var numbersArray = [10, 49, 90, 110, 150, 69, 59, 20, 20, 30];
            for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
            //any constructor magic to make this refer to the number?


                $('#data').append(numbersArray[i]).append('<br/>');

            }
        });
```

Let's say that I had a lot of work to do inside of this loop.  Could I make my code shorter and I think maybe more readable by changing the meaning of `this`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$.each`

```
$.each([10, 49, 90, 110, 150, 69, 59, 20, 20, 30], function(){
    // this is an instance of number whose value is the number
});
```

This is probably what you want.

Comment: Yep.  I was going to make a heat map type thing where the numbers are rgb values and I can style a jQuery object rgb value easily.

Comment: Be just careful to a pitfall : `$.each([10], function(){ console.log(this===10) })` will log false. But you're fine if you use `==`. [I explain it on my blog](http://canop.org/blog/?p=307).

Answer (score 3):

If this is all you are planning to do then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numbersArray = [10, 49, 90, 110, 150, 69, 59, 20, 20, 30];   
    $('#data').append(numbersArray.join('<br/>'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7B6R6/)

If you want to loop and use `this` reference then use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numbersArray = [10, 49, 90, 110, 150, 69, 59, 20, 20, 30];

    $.each(numbersArray, function () {
        $('#data').append(this).append('<br/>');
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/auvz9/)